# Different reuseIdentifier in xib and by registration, what are the side effects?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

In my xib, I set the reuse identifier of the cell to A

but then in `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` I declare "B"

```
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"A" bundle:nil]
 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"B"];
```

what are the effects of such behaviour? all looks running ok, why there are 2 places to enter the reuse identifier?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the reuseIdentifier field in the xib.

Because that option is actually pretty useless when you are dealing with xibs. It's probably there just because Xcode uses the exact same User Interface as it uses when editing storyboards.
Compared to storyboard, in xibs there is no connection between the cell and the tableView. The cell is even stored in a different file. So the cell won't, and can't be dequeued/created with its reuseIdentifier.

If you have a cell in a xib you have to register it in code. This process creates the connection between the tableView and the cell (or its xib).

Comment: so when i use custom xib, than the property is ignored and only the value from [self.tableView registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:IDENTIFIER] is used? but what happens when i load the cell manually with UIView * cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(cellClass) owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];